# TeXstudio should not automatically sync between PDF viewer and LaTeX source

Tags: texstudio, viewers

The embedded PDF viewer in TeXstudio loads and opens automatically the corresponding LaTeX files when I scroll through the PDF document. Since I have a lot of LaTeX files I would like to open the corresponding LaTeX file only on request (e.g. via context menu entry "Goto sourcecode"). Is this somehow possible?

Comment: you can only disable `synctex` for all files

Comment: When I write a document with multiple .tex files with `include` and if I travel along the pdf document, if I click on "go to source", it opens the right .tex file even if it is not already open.

Is that your question ?

Comment: I just want to switch out the automatic opening of the corresponding LaTeX source files; only open on request.

Comment: Meaning you want to use your IDE as an ordinary PDF viewer? (I guess I don't understand the question).

Comment: Nope. TeXstudio  opens now a lot of (small) LaTeX files when I scroll through the  PDF view. I not even touched these files or plan to touch them. Thus, I want to keep the functionality but want to switch out the automatic opening.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can deactivate the forward and/or reverse synchronization in the statusbar of the viewer:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the new version TeXstudio 3.1.2 the option for disabling the sync, is on the bottom left in the pdf side.
[image]